# Cant build Cordova ios. Error 65

Tags: ios, iphone, node.js, cordova

My steps to make app:
I installed node js
I installed cordova: `sudo npm install -g cordova`
Then: `npm install -g ios-sim`
      `npm install -g ios-deploy`
Also I downloaded simulator

Now I should be able to make project so:

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
cd hello
cordova platform add ios --save
cordova build
```

With "cordova build" this error appears:

```
The following build commands failed:
CompileXIB HelloWorld/Classes/MainViewController.xib
(1 failure)
Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/xXx/Desktop/Radko/hello/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,HelloWorld.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,HelloWorld,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/xXx/Desktop/Radko/hello/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/xXx/Desktop/Radko/hello/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
```

Working on it for two days and no difference.

Comment: ANSWER: you need to use SUDO. Like: sudo cordova build.

Comment: @Radolnko You can create a new project and port your code and try building iOS platform again. This solves the issue in most cases. Also ensure that you dont have any illegal or special characters in config.xml. Many a times, copy paste results in special characters addition in config.xml which causes this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Radolnko

Run (This will remove the old cardova ios platform)

```
sudo cordova platform rm ios
```

Then (This will install a new platform with privileges)

```
sudo cordova platform add ios
```

Then

```
cordova build
```

This fixed it for me!

Comment: Why do you need `sudo`?

Comment: It could be done with out sudo, but I had to use it on my system.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was unchecking my app at `Target Membership` section in the `.xib` file itself.

Open the `.xib` file with xcode and in the right section at the bottom under `Target Membership` you will see a checkbox with your app's name. 
Uncheck it!!!